# Extract information from one column to create separate columns for each value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have zero experience of programming so I apologise if this seems a stupid question. I have been given a dataset of information on airports and asked to load this into a pandas dataframe which I have done. One of the columns 'Type' has different categories. I am being tasked with taking the information in this column and separating it into new columns for each category. [image: image to show the date set I am working with]

I need to take large_airport, medium_airport and small_airport from the 'type column and create three new columns, one for each. I have been trying to find away to do this but I cannot find an answer. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a dataframe of three columns and filled it with 1, 2, 3.
But I assume that the value of the columns needs to be filled with something else?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'large_airport': [1, 2, 3], 'medium_airport': [1, 2, 3], 'small_airport': [1, 2, 3]})
    print(data)


"""
   large_airport  medium_airport  small_airport
0              1               1              1
1              2               2              2
2              3               3              3
"""
```